# documents don't go into newly added shard

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have added a shard to an existing cluster, and when I do db.printShardingStatus() I see a distribution:

```
mongos> db.printShardingStatus()
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("5c84149e75f51a74e9796add")
  }
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "127.0.0.1:27023",  "state" : 1 }
        {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "127.0.0.1:27024",  "state" : 1 }
        {  "_id" : "shard0002",  "host" : "localhost:27025",  "state" : 1 }
  active mongoses:
        "4.0.6" : 1
  autosplit:
        Currently enabled: yes
  balancer:
        Currently enabled:  yes
        Currently running:  no
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  3
        Last reported error:  Error connecting to localhost:27025 (127.0.0.1:27025) :: caused by :: Connection refused
        Time of Reported error:  Sat Mar 09 2019 20:55:55 GMT+0000 (UTC)
        Migration Results for the last 24 hours: 
                8 : Success
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "config",  "primary" : "config",  "partitioned" : true }
                config.system.sessions
                        shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                shard0000   1
                        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 0) 
        {  "_id" : "testdb",  "primary" : "shard0001",  "partitioned" : true,  "version" : {  "uuid" : UUID("68b7f8fe-17f6-4049-87ce-6c616c7746b7"),  "lastMod" : 1 } }
                testdb.testcollection
                        shard key: { "testkey" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                shard0000   3
                                shard0001   3
                                shard0002   1
                        { "testkey" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "testkey" : "key0" } on : shard0002 Timestamp(9, 0) 
                        { "testkey" : "key0" } -->> { "testkey" : "key20968" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(7, 1) 
                        { "testkey" : "key20968" } -->> { "testkey" : "key4265" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(4, 0) 
                        { "testkey" : "key4265" } -->> { "testkey" : "key53621" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(6, 0) 
                        { "testkey" : "key53621" } -->> { "testkey" : "key64595" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(5, 1) 
                        { "testkey" : "key64595" } -->> { "testkey" : "key8552" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(9, 1) 
                        { "testkey" : "key8552" } -->> { "testkey" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard0001 Timestamp(4, 1)
```

But when I access the newly added shard (shard0002), the collection is empty? Does anyone know why?

Comment: Adding a shard to a cluster creates an imbalance, since the new shard has no chunks. While MongoDB begins migrating data to the new shard immediately, `it can take some time before the cluster balances`. Are you still with same status?

Comment: @tomdinh, What is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Comment: @tomdinh, At existing shard, how many nodes is there?

Comment: I solved it. had to wait for a while for rebalancing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Add Shards to a Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/add-shards-to-shard-cluster/)

As mentioned in MongoDB documentation,

> Adding a shard to a cluster creates an imbalance since the new shard
>   has no chunks. While MongoDB begins migrating data to the new shard
>   immediately, **it can take some time before the cluster balances**.